# Как организовать связи для таблиц бд?

Tags: база-данных, связи, sequelize.js

Мне нужно правильно установить связи между таблицами.

Есть таблицы Orders, Invoices и Users.

К примеру таблица Orders состоит из полей (Id, startDate, finalDate, price).

К примеру таблица Invoices состоит из полей (Id, startDate, finalDate, totalPrice).

К примеру таблица Users состоит из полей (Id, username, email, password).

*Поля таблиц выше не содержат связных полей.

Связи (пока что я так вижу связи)

```
db.users.hasMany(db.invoices);
db.users.hasMany(db.orders);
//
db.orders.belongsTo(db.users);
db.orders.belongsTo(db.invoices);
//
db.invoices.belongsTo(db.users);
db.invoices.hasMany(db.orders);
```

Когда делается заказ OrderController не знает о конечных счетах, он просто добавляет новый заказ с привязкой к пользователю.

Когда делается запрос счетов (список), InvoiceController получает последний счет из бд, проверяет даты, если счет старый создает новый из заказов для текущего месяца. Делается запрос заказов связанных с Users по выбранным датам. И общая сумма счетов добавляется в поле totalPrice.

Если счет текущего месяца то делается запрос заказов связанных с Users по выбранным датам. И общая сумма счетов обновляется в поле totalPrice.

И далее делается запрос всех счетов связанных с Users (список).

Если пользователь хочет посмотреть один счет, делается запрос заказов связанных с Users по выбранным датам и второй запрос к Invoices получить данные счета. Формируется json и отправляется клиенту.

Что то не пойму, как лучше сделать связи между таблицами исходя из этой логики.

Answer (score -1):

Необходимо настроить связь сущностей Invoice to Orders.
Исходя из вашей бизнес логики, я бы сделал так для Invoice:

```
    HasMany(o => o.Orders).WithOptional(i => i.Invoice);
```

Таким образом, создастся связь один cчет ко многим заказам. При этом, наличие связи не обязательно для обеих сущностей. По логике, при запросе счета, проверяется таблица заказов, если есть не связанные со счетом, добавляете связи. 
Ну и конечно же, удостоверьтесь, есть ли навигационные свойства в настраиваемых сущностях

Comment: То, что при запросе счета проверяются навые заказы, связи это понятно. А при создании заказа как устанавливается связь именно к этому счету?

Comment: Смотрите выше. Я писал вам, связь не обязательная. Заказ может жить в базе как связанным, так и не связанным, на совести программиста остается код проверки и отбора соотвествующих условию заказов. Таким образом, выполняются требования, указанные вами в задании.

Comment: А к чему тогда вообще тут нужны связи? Я вас не достаточно понимаю.  При связи один счет ко многим заказам предполагается, что в таблице Orders будет поле invoiceId. Это значит, что при создании заказа мне нужно сначала узнать id счета т.е. создать его или узнать его из таблицы Invoices. Получается каждый раз создавая счет мы обращаемся в таблицу Invoices и Orders и для формирования счета в таблицу Orders и Invoices. Если нет связей, при создания заказа я обращаюсь только в таблицу Orders, а при формировании счета в таблицу Orders и Invoices. Получается без связей телодвижений с базой меньше.

Comment: Во первых, связи нужны для того, чтобы было удобнее взаимодействовать с сущностями. Разные отборы на основании связей, и т.п. Во вторых, связями описываются требования бизнес логики, это такая штука, которая должна работать на уровне базы данных и кода приложения, и работать идеально, без всяких там ошибок. Это данность, которую необходимо всегда держать в уме.

Comment: Теперь по вашему пониманию EF. Никаких Id счета и заказа вам знать не нужно. Это чисто навигационные поля, по своей сути. Они должны генерироваться базой автоматически, при создании записи. Второе, вы совершенно напрасно зациклены на обращениях к таблицам. На старте, на котором вы находитесь, об этом думать рано. Есть смысл думать когда поджимает производительность. Забудьте про это, болшинству проектов малого/среднего уровня производительности EF хватает с головой.

Comment: Зачем вам узнавать Id счета? Если он у вас один в месяц, выбирайте из таблицы последний, да и все. Тут же привязывайте к нему необходимое количество заказов. Либо добавляйте те, которые еще не привязаны. Телодвижения с базой, производятся один единственный раз, когда EF сохраняет состояние контекста в базу либо выбирает что то. Все остальное время, все что вы выбрали, и обрабатываете, болтается в оперативке, на сервере. Т.е. при прочих равных, телодвижения с базой, начнут вас волновать когда данных будет очень много. Рекомендую разобраться со связями сущностей в EF, сэкономите кучу времени.

Comment: Поле invoiceId в заказе - nullable. Это означает что он может быть связан со счетом, а может и нет. Вам его не обязательно указывать вручную, пропишите связь через fluent api, и EF создаст его автоматом. Так же, при создании связи заказа со счетом, навигационные поля обновятся автоматически. И да, еще момент. Никогда не переживайте по поводу обращений к базе. Лучше дополнительно сделать запрос к базе, на проверку сущностей, их полей, и содержимого, чем ловить где-то в коде, то ли вы обновляете, изменились ли данные, и т.д.

Comment: Вот вам пример. Вы уехали жить в другую страну. Ваш работодатель, которому вы писали проект, приглашает меня, доработать функционал. Как я должен понять, какая логика взаимодействия сущностей заложена в вашем приложении? Искать по коду и разбираться как вы создаете или обновляете сущности? А если это например какое-то допущение, и вообще, чем вы руководствовались, когда писали код, неизвестно. Но, если есть связи в базе, по ним отлично видно все отношения.

Comment: К тому же, это сейчас у вас 2-3 сущности, когда их будет 30-50, вы в голове будете держать логику их взаимодействия? При всем прочем, с помощью жестких связей можно задать те или иные обязательные условия в приложении, и все это будет прозрачно и понятно. А обрабатывающий эти сущности код, это дело второе.

Comment: Что такое EF? Id счета, ну у меня же множество пользователей у которых у каждого свой счет и не факт, что мой счет будет последним. Отсюда я вывел для себя, что связь должна быть, если со связями так: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#belongs-to-many-associations или так: http://rusrails.ru/active-record-associations#the-has-many-through-association в моем случае я иcпользую sequelize.js.

Comment: Простите, но где в вопросе есть хоть слово про то что используется EF?